# First layer problem

Tags: creality-ender-3, troubleshooting, bltouch, adhesion

I have Ender 3 v2 with BLTouch and Marlin 2.0.x software

There is a problem on the first layer it allows come wrong the last problem I have it is the first layer it is not constant on the bed it comes good in some area and the worst in other areas with BLTouch install any help why did that happen?

These parts are printed together:

[image]

Edit: this is photo after z hop the extrusion is not constant.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked that the Y-axis is not wobbly?

Comment: Considering this is a wheel carriages operated printer, you should definitely check the rollers of the Y carriage and the non driven Z side carriage. Although a popular design, it has its flaws, problems with the (eccentric nut) rollers is one of these.

Comment: Yes I checked Y-axis and there is no problem. For the Z-axis I already ordered the second rod drive for Z

Answer (score 2):

There could be multiple reasons for this happening, the most probable cause would be that the bed isn't leveled properly, if you have an auto leveling bed I'd suggest that you give that a run through, I also found it personally helpful with mine (Ender 5 Plus) that if I did the manual leveling, so the four corners, then go and do the auto leveling. Another thing could be that the tip is snagging on the print, so make sure you clean that, and its also helpful if you add z hop if your printer supports that (the extruder will hop up when its not pushing filament out

Comment: Already the four corners are leveled manually before the print and I already make auto bed leveling with BLTouch, what do you mean by the tip is managing on the printer? Also, I will try z hop to see if that will solve my problem.

Comment: After add ing z hop there is improvement but still the result a bad print

Comment: @HazemIsmail You should try to do a temp tower so you know what temp your printer prints best at. And also if you change the filament print width, even if you have a .4mm nozel, if you choose something like .3mm or .2mm it will print the lines closer together and that might work.